# django admin cascade dropdownlist

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-admin

*model.py*

```
class CaseTitle(BaseModel):
        Description = models.CharField(max_length=500)

        def __str__(self):
            return  self.Description

    class CaseCategory(BaseModel):
        Description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        CaseTitle = models.ManyToManyField(CaseTitle)
```

my scenario is when i select casetitle, CaseCategory must be fill according to CaseTitleID [image: simplfy like that].

Answer (score 0):

I think it's solution is you can use [django-smart-select](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects) to reflect that in CaseCategory field. It's called chain selection in django. I hope it helps you. Let me update that. It is working or not. Thanks.

Comment: i really dont remember :( do you have a another idea ?